# IDAPYTHON got wrong data from memory

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I wrote a script to show the second param of `NtQueryInformationProcess`.however,I always got wrong data,it seems like the memory wasn't freshed and what I got was old data.Here is my code:

```
from idaapi import *
NtQueryInformationProcess=0x7798E740
class HookNQIP(DBG_Hooks):
    def dbg_bpt(self,tid,ea):
        if ea==NtQueryInformationProcess:
            print 'ProcessInformationClass:',hex(Dword(GetRegValue('ESP')+8))
AddBpt(NtQueryInformationProcess)
func=HookNQIP()
func.hook()
```

IDA 6.9 on Win10-64,thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my fault to ask this question while here is an answer:
[IDA Python - Why My code return incorrect ESP Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076730/ida-python-why-my-code-return-incorrect-esp-value)

So the solution is adding code `RefreshDebuggerMemory()` to fresh memory

In fact I've search word 'fresh' in idapython's docs,but there is too many things on that page so I've got nothing cause I closed that page before all the things were loaded,that's really a mistake.